# How do I make this bathroom concrete slab as thin as possible?

Tags: bathroom, concrete, drain, toilet, pipe

Renovating my bathroom in an old 1890s apartment in Denmark and changing all the pipework

I am unable to go to my downstairs neighbor to do the drain pipes, so I'm stuck with this long 10 cm / 4 inch diameter drain pipe for the toilet that rests on top of the beams (see picture)

I need to figure out what structure to do the floor with that will add the least amount of height.

My plumber says I need likely need to cover the drain pipes with 5 cm (2 inches) mesh armed quality concrete

This means the excess floor height of the bathroom compared to the rest of the bathroom will be 15 cm + 2 cm for tile and slope (6.7 inches in total).

I understand my main constraint here is the large diameter drain pipe (legal requirement where I am) and not being able to bury that (hindered by the beams).

BUT - is there anything I'm missing or can do smarter in terms of the concrete construction on top of it where I can shave of a few centimeters? Naturally I don't want a too thin layer of concrete that will crack and make the tiles crack as well.

Thank you.

[image: New drain pipework]

Comment: FYI, a floor slab is not a foundation. The slab rests _on_ the foundation and does not carry any structural load.

Comment: The left-most pipe seems to go under a bit of an overhang that looks like it's more than tall enough to clear the large, main drain line. If you cover all this as described, wouldn't you just be bringing the floor level up to this bit at the far left edge of the picture? Or is that bit at the left actually a wall and perspective just makes it look like a raised floor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideas:

A:  Rearrange the bathroom to put the toilet as close to the down pipe as possible.  This may allow you to have the toilet and bathtub on a raised platform at one end of the room, while the rest is at normal or closer to normal height.

B: Route the pipes at the extreme edge of the room.  YOu end up with a sill around the edge.

C: Presumably you have some form of underslab?  Instead of pouring concrete, putting in plywood floor supported on blocks.  This will be thinner than the 2" over the pipes.

D: Instead of tile, use some form of sheet flooring  'vinyl' or 'linoleum'.  (I don't know what this sort of material is called in Europe.)  This gains you at least 2 cm

E:  Put in cleanout port access

F:  Here they sell a 'basement toilet system' that has a macerator and a small sewage pump that can use a much smaller line. It's used in situations where the sewer line is above the desired features. I've no idea about the working dimensions of it.

Comment: What sort of sill are you describing in B? Do you mean multiple floor heights?

Comment: @isherwood Yes. Imagine a ledge 8" tall, 8" wide (something like that) around the room. An architectural feature to (as is often the case with "features") hide the functional pipes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a masonry expert, and I'm not clear on what support exists for your slab, but I'd probably reduce the thickness of the slab over the pipe to say 1" and use an isolation system over the slab for your tile. This eliminates the effect of the inevitable crack over the pipe.

Also consider fiber in your concrete mix, possibly *along with* mesh.

This strategy depends on good support for the slab. I'm assuming that most or all of the concrete we see in the photo can bear weight. If so, the slab doesn't span more than a short distance in any one area.